# How can a JSON key be renamed using Play 2.5 JSON transformations?

Tags: json, playframework

I Just want to rename "x3" to "k3" using Play's 2.5 *JSON coast-to-coast* features, but how?

Here's the JSON source:

```
{"k1":"K1", "k2":"K2","x3":"K3"}
```

and here's the desired result

```
{"k1":"K1", "k2":"K2","k3":"K3"}
```

Here's the Scala not working code snippet:

```
( (__ \ 'x3  ).json.update( (__ \ 'k3).json.pick ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not rename key with transformer, so use must **update** Json by **copying** value **from** x3 key and **remove** original key:

```
__.json.update(
  (__\"k3").json.copyFrom(
    (__\"x3").json.pick
  )
) andThen 
(__\"x3").json.prune
```